# Rails 5: Populate Dropdown List from Database with options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I am new to rails and have read documentation on drop downs, but am still struggling.

I have a database as follows:

```
                        Table "public.lakeaddresses"
Column  |         Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 address | character varying(40) |           | extended |              |
 city    | character varying(25) |           | extended |              |
 state   | character varying(20) |           | extended |              |
 zip     | integer               |           | plain    |              |
 county  | character varying(25) |           | extended |              |
 lake    | character varying(30) |           | extended |              |
 lakeid  | integer               |           | plain    |              |
```

I want to create a dropdown list that populates the name of the lakes, which would be column "lake"

views/map/index.html.erb

```
<head>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.26.0/mapbox-gl.js'>    
</script>
<link href='/home/garrett/lakemag/app/assets/stylesheets/lakemap.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>          

<body>
<div  id='map' style='margin:0 auto; width: 1024px; height: 768px;'>
<script>
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZ3JhZmZpbmR1c3RyaWVzIiwiYSI6ImNpdXAxY2pycjAxeGoyb251dDY2emNqeXgifQ.YtJkR5Elp-oq3FaMTUlXyw';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/graffindustries/ciursnqrv009u2js5cpedcnsr'
  });
</script>
</div>

</br></br>

<center>

<% form_tag(method: "get") do %>
  <% lake_array = Lake.all.map { |lake| [lake.name] } %>
  <= select_tag 'Lake Name', options_for_select(lake_array) %>
<% end %>

</center>
</body>
```

controllers/map_controller.rb

```
def new
@lake = Lake.all
```

Error received:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Lake
18:
19: <center>
20:
21: <% form_tag(method: "get") do %>
22: <% lake_array = Lake.all.map { |lake| [lake.name] } %>
23: <= select_tag 'Lake Name', options_for_select(lake_array) %>
24: <% end %>
25:
26: </center>
F, [2016-11-02T06:22:04.619269 #7096] FATAL -- : [f4086edc-8de8-4b36-9b81-4a20efbde333] app/views/map/index.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_map_index_html_erb___3432893749292109102_24860500'
```

Comment: Could you post your entire view file ?

Comment: I have updated the view file. the code for the map on the page works fine - but once i add the code for the form it breaks the page. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@lake, 'lake') %>`

Try establishing your array in this manner.

```
<% lake_array = Map.all.map { |map| [map.lake] } %>
<%= select_tag 'Lake Name', options_for_select(lake_array) %>
```

Kindly note that unless you are using a `form_for` you cannot use `f.select` and instead have to use `select_tag`

Update: You were receiving the error because `lake` is derived from the `map` table. If you had a `lake.rb` model with table column `name` you could do something like this in your rails console.

```
lake = Lake.first
lake_name = lake.name
```

However right now, because you cannot access `Lake.method` like this, you have to access it through your `Map` instead. So for example, in order to access one of your lake names, in your rails console, you have to do this.

```
map = Map.first
lake_name = map.lake 
#this would return the lake that is tied to the first map object
```

Hopefully this clears up your doubt and explains why you are receiving the error.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your solution and am now getting a new error. I have updated my errorfile response as well as my view file in the original post. thanks for taking the time to reply to my question

Comment: Your form needs to be included in a `form_tag` and not just included right into your `index.html.erb` view. Do kindly read up about forms and not just `select` tags

Comment: I've updated my view code with a form_tag beginning and end. could you kindly tell me if I"m on the right track?

Comment: Technically yes, although it depends on what your form/select tag is meant to achieve.

Comment: I understand that form_for would expect to build a form from a model. I am confused as to why I receive the error:
    `ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Lake`

Comment: thank you. so, first things first, should I be creating a model named "lakeaddresses" that matches the name of my table in the database, or have I completely diverged from your point? I created a map.rb model because I figured it should match the view.

Comment: I cannot recommend what you should do because i do not know your exact needs. What i would say you should do though is to read up on the MVC concept so you would know what relevant Model, Controller and Views you would need. But you are right that you should be creating a `map.rb` model which matches both the view, controller and also the table name in your `schema.rb`